# findContours returns contour with duplicate points

Tags: python, opencv, contour

OpenCV's findContours sometimes returns bad results

The code snippet attempts to find the largest contour in the edge images.

In the "bad" example, it seems as though most vertex's of the contour are needlessly duplicated. This causes a subsequent wrong contourArea and pointPolygonTest behavior.

```
import cv2
import imutils
from scipy import misc

edges = misc.imread('edges3.png')

cnts = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
sorted_cnts = sorted(cnts, key = lambda c:cv2.arcLength(c,True), reverse = True)
largest_cnt = sorted_cnts[0]

print("Largest contour area",cv2.contourArea(largest_cnt))
print("Largest contour arc length",cv2.arcLength(largest_cnt,True))
print("Largest contour num of vertx",len(largest_cnt))
```

[image]

**Bad** code output:

> ```
> Largest contour area 14.0
> Largest contour arc length 2639.200133085251
> Largest contour num of vertx 667
> ```

[image]

**Good** code output:

> ```
> Largest contour area 95534.0
> Largest contour arc length 1321.8721450567245
> Largest contour num of vertx 340
> ```

The two attached photos are almost identical and should return similar results. However, the first returns a contour with a very small area, and double the arc length and vertex number compared to second one.

Comment: can you post your output and what you want to achieve in hand drawing? so that others can help you?

Comment: it looks a reasonable number. Are you thinking it is too much point for the largest rectangular looking thing? You have to keep in mind that contour is a vector of points for as accurate approximation as possible.   if you want the minimum representation, you can use convex hull (guess it can get 4<vertics<20) or min rect (4 vertics) for the largest contour.

Comment: The main problem is the area which is 14 instead of 100,000. The underling root cause of the wrong reading is the duplicated vertexes.

Comment: Looks like a bug when dealing with complex shape.  The contour area function is calling https://github.com/barak/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp icvContourArea which is counting line by line for starting and ending of the shape. aka dxy. Need to do more test to give you a valid fix on the source code.  Meanwhile  can you use convexhull output  vector<point> as the source to the countour area? for simple case, there shouldn`t be issue.    Additional info. which opencv version are you using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant upload picture in a comment. Is it possible that your edge detection has some fault and there is some minor opening? the resulting is top is counting the area next to the edge and break by opening. And bottom is counting the whole image?  The blue area denotes the actual counted area. Because there is a break in the edge detection, then the area is actually pretty small. It is common for edge to partially fail on a few points.

if the assumption is there is some pixel break (you line is not continuous), the result form this assumption fits your description of

A. a very small area,

B. double the arc length and vertex number

C. Some point are duplicated as they are on the same line.

[image]

To deal with this opening is using morphological dilate or convex hull to close the gap.

Comment: This worked for me: I used kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
edges = cv2.dilate(edges,kernel,iterations = 1) to dilate the edges

Comment: congraz, carry on. guess you have to do sth with that number for a project.